# The type of quickCheck input

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm trying to learn QuickCheck  and understand how it works. The data type of the quickCheck  function is

```
quickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()
```

On the other hand I have a function

```
prop_rev_involutive:Eq a => [a] -> Bool
prop_rev_involutive l = (reverse $ reverse l) == l
```

that I'm using for input for quickCheck. Running  `quickCheck   prop_rev_involutive`
works fine but I don't understand how the types are matching.

is the type  `[a] -> Bool`  considered to be `Testable`? Why is this?

Comment: Hint: look at the instances for [`Testable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Testable). Also, remember to think about type defaulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Testable` is a *type class* - essentially an abstraction over things that can be turned into an automated test. The type class has several instances, one of which is `Bool`:

```
Testable Bool
```

That's not the type of `prop_rev_involutive`, though. Another instance of `Testable` is:

```
(Arbitrary a, Show a, Testable prop) => Testable (a -> prop)
```

This declares that for any `a` which is an instance of both `Arbitrary` and `Show`, a function from `a` to `prop` is itself `Testable`. We've already established that `Bool` is a `Testable` instance, so now you need to investigate whether `[a]` is an `Arbitrary` and `Show` instance.

The `Arbitrary` type class has a ton of instances, one of which is:

```
Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [a]
```

This declares that if `a` is an `Arbitrary` instance, then so is `[a]`. So, is `a` an `Arbitrary` instance? That depends on which concrete type you actually run `quickCheck` with. Some Haskell environments default to certain types (e.g. `Int`, which *is* an `Arbitrary` instance).

You'll need to go through the same line of reasoning for the `Show` type class.

I don't think that any unconstrained function `[a] -> Bool` is a `Testable` instance, but something like `(Arbitrary a, Show a) => [a] -> Bool` is. Examples include `[Int] -> Bool` and `[Char] -> Bool`. This is because `Bool` is `Testable`, and `Int` and `Char` are both `Arbitrary` and `Show` instances.